# Why Code Runner always open other terminal in VSCode when I execute Python? And how to fix it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Even though there is already a terminal open, when I run `Python` code using `Code Runner` (`ctrl + alt + n`), in VSCode it always opens another terminal. And it's no use closing the old one, because it opens again.

[image]

This is my configurations for terminal, Python and Code Runner:

Terminal:

```
"terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection": true,
"terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true,
"terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line",
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
"terminal.integrated.letterSpacing": 1,
```

Code Runner:

```
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true, //only 2 Python
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "javascript": "node",

    "python": "venv\\Scripts\\python.exe -u", //code-runner exec python of venv
    "bat": "cmd /c"
},
```

Python:

```
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"files.autoSaveDelay": 500,

"[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
    "editor.insertSpaces": true
},

"python.pythonPath": "venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pycodestylePath": "[MyPathHere]",
"python.linting.flake8Path": "[MyPathHere]",
"python.formatting.provider": "black"
```

**How I can fix this strange behavior?**

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with code runners clear previous output , set it to false and add clear command manually to its executor map, the final result should look like this. All this is to be done in the project's settings.json file, under .vscode folder.

```
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": false,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "c": "clear; cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && 
                   $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "cpp": "clear; cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && 
                   $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    }
}
```

Comment: REALLY thx! Someone finally resolved this annoying issue.