Why is VS Code creating a new terminal when running a code after reopening the application?
I ran a Python code in VS Code and everything worked fine, but after closing VS Code and reopening it, running the same program that I ran last time before closing the application creates a new terminal. Even if I close the new terminal and run the program again, it creates another new terminal. How can I stop this?

This question should be what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835304/why-code-runner-always-open-other-terminal-in-vscode-when-i-execute-python-and

So when you close VSC, you leave the terminal running, yeah? Then when you reopen it, the terminal gets restored? And you're expecting a new run of the program to use the restored terminal? Please [edit] to clarify. It seems to me like closing and reopening VSC severs the association between the code and the terminal, but IDK what your setup is (extension that runs the code, config), so I'm not sure.

I see you asked another question that could be related to this: How to remove warning about "git auth provider"
